# Cache decorator for data structures

Tags: python, caching, decorator

The implementation of lru_cache in functools only support hashable arguments.

I'm trying to make it work for any structure with a __ str __ method implementation by combining 3 decorators in a single one: One that convert the structure to string (hashable data), one for the cache using the string, and one that recovers the data structure from the string data.
I don't like the last decorator, since it requires remaking the whole data from a string, which can be computationally expensive. It could also be the case that the structure can't be recovered from the string version with a literal_eval operation.

Is there any better way to refactor this so it uses the original input data, rather than recovering it from a string? If there is an out of the box implementation for this, that would be helpful too.

```
from functools import lru_cache
from ast import literal_eval

def data_2_str(f):    
    def wrapper(*data):
        string_data = str(data)
        return f(string_data)
    return wrapper

def str_2_data(f):    
    def wrapper(string_data):
        
        data = literal_eval(string_data)
        return f(*data)
    return wrapper

def string_lru_cache(maxsize:int=128):
    def wrapper1(f):
        @data_2_str
        @lru_cache(maxsize=maxsize)
        @str_2_data
        def wrapper2(*data):
            return f(*data)
        return wrapper2
    return wrapper1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from time import sleep, time
    from typing import List
    
    class Pipeline:
        def __init__(self):
            @string_lru_cache(maxsize=2)
            def operation( numbers:List[float])->float:
                sleep(2)
                return sum(numbers)
            self.operation = operation
    
    p = Pipeline()
    
    t0 = time()
    p.operation([1,2,3,4,5])
    print("operation time:", time()-t0)
    t0 = time()
    p.operation([1,2,3,4,5])
    print("operation time:", time()-t0)
```

$ python utils_cache.py

operation time: 2.004383087158203

operation time: 2.3126602172851562e-05